# Auto detect history in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I've seen when people are typing in their terminal it shows an auto suggestion in gray based on their history as they're typing.

How can I have that in my terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have seen someone using the `fish` shell which has this form of autocompletion built in.

Check out https://fishshell.com/ there are appropriate packages for most versions and derivatives of Linux distros; and of course there is a version that you can install with `apt` on Ubuntu.

Comment: But they used konsole, idk how

Comment: `Konsole` is the presentation layer (the view on the desktop). It will display whatever shell your user account is setup to use: bash, ksh, tcsh, zsh, and fish can all be used (that isn't an exhaustive list either).